Person of Interest - Where Finch snoops on a bunch of webcams in an apartment building?
I'm trying to figure out which Person of Interest episode had a certain scene. I don't recall the particular plot of the episode, but the scene I'm looking for had Finch set up in an apartment with his laptop or other computer. He was using the computer to snoop on the webcams in numerous other apartments within the same building.
He wasn't using any special access from The Machine - at that point in the series, I'm pretty sure the only interaction they'd had with it was the receiving of numbers. Finch was simply exploiting common weaknesses in WiFi networks and networked cameras with his own hardware and hacking tools.
The scene stuck out for me because it's a fairly rare case of Hollywood more or less getting hacking right. Sure, the actual implementation is still a bit separated from reality. But what Finch was accomplishing isn't really all that far from what is actually possible given a target-rich environment where people will commonly just stand up their WiFi and webcams with default (and generally weak) security options.
What season and episode number was this, or what was the episode called?

Sounds like Super (Season 1, episode 11), where they investigate a superintendent. From TVTropes:

Reese and Finch hack into the Wi-Fi of everyone in an apartment building so they can access the webcams. One woman is doing yoga in full view of her webcam. In her underwear. 


Sounds familiar. The super being involved seems about right. Now if I could just find a good streaming source for it to check.

It's all just a big homage to Rear Window, really (Reese is in a wheelchair spying on tenants).

@Iszi Er, was the answer correct in the end?

@Walt I believe this answer is correct. Same episode came in my mind after reading the question
